# SwiftUI HStack top alignment doesn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was trying to align Text (`Test` in the picture) in HStack to top, but HStack align doesn't work. It's still in the center.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YiDY.png)

Here's my code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Text("Test")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: 480, height: 160)
            HStack {
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum."
                )
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .frame(
                    minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity,
                    alignment: .topLeading
                )
                .padding()
            }
            .frame(width: 480, height: 320)
            .background(Color(.white))
        }
        .frame(width: 480, height: 480)
        .background(
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(
                        LinearGradient(
                            gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .red]),
                            startPoint: .topLeading,
                            endPoint: .bottomTrailing
                        )
                    )
                    .blur(radius: 10)

                VisualEffectView(
                    material: .toolTip,
                    blendingMode: .withinWindow
                )
            }
        )
        .mask(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: There might be couple reasons why it's happening. If you remove the frame of your 
 top `HStack` and parent `VStack` you'll see it actually stick to the top so it's due to manual spacing. 

You could remove those frame to fit to the content (and use padding / margin instead) or you could add a `VStack` + `Spacer` as parent to your top `HStack` to keep your current frame dimensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add alignment in frame

```
        HStack {
            Text("Test")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 480, height: 160, alignment: .top)   // << here !!
```

Comment: It's nice.. but don't know why its in frame?

Comment: @Asperi can you explain why this is working and `HStack(alignment: .top)` is not?